# combining 3 ratio together with no equal volumes

Tags: arithmetic

An Alloy A contains copper and tin in the ratio of 3 : 5 by weight. Another Alloy B contains tin and zinc in the ratio 3:7 by weight . Find the ratio of copper : tin : zinc in a new alloy containing equal weights of alloys A And B

They are not equal in volume so I can't combine them together , so how do I approach this question to combine to form a new alloy of 3 elements ?

Comment: @almagest how do u know that copper in A is 0.75 and Tin in A is 1.25 ?

Comment: Sorry, error. Corrected version below.

Answer (score 1):

The data is given by weight. So assume we take weight 1 of alloy A and weight 1 of alloy B. Then the amount of Cu is $\frac{3}{3+5}\times1=\frac{3}{8}=0.375$ and the amount of Sn is $\frac{5}{3+5}=0.625$. From alloy B we get $\frac{3}{7}-0.3$ of Sn and $\frac{7}{3+7}=0.7$ of Zn. So in total in a weight 2 of new alloy we have 0.375 Cu, 0.925 Sn and 0.7 Zn (check: 0.375+0.925+0.7=2). As a ratio this is Cu:Sn:Zn=0.375:0.925:0.7=15:37:28.